# ansible.builtin.uri expects a base64 body

Tags: curl, ansible, base64, databricks

I have an Ansible task that performs a curl on the databricks API. Here's what it looks like :

```yaml
---
- name: Databricks dbfs upload
  shell: "curl -H 'Authorization: Bearer {{ token }}' \
    -F filedata=config-file/application.conf \
    -F path=/destpath/on/dbfs/application.conf \
    https://<instance_name>.azuredatabricks.net/api/2.0/dbfs/put"
```

I want to replace that curl with the `ansible.builtin.uri` [method](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/uri_module.html), but I encounter the following error:

```json
{
  ...
  "json": {
    "error_code": "MALFORMED_REQUEST", 
    "message": "Could not parse request object: Unexpected end of base64-encoded String: base64 variant 'MIME-NO-LINEFEEDS' expects padding (one or more '=' characters) at the end. This Base64Variant might have been incorrectly configured\n at [Source: (ByteArrayInputStream); line: 1, column: 36]\n at [Source: java.io.ByteArrayInputStream@35649c34; line: 1, column: 36]"
  }, 
  "msg": "Status code was 400 and not [200]: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request"
  ...
}
```

Here is what my new `databricks_upload.yml` file looks like :

```yaml
---
- name: Databricks dbfs upload
  ansible.builtin.uri:
    url: https://<instance_name>.azuredatabricks.net/api/2.0/dbfs/put
    method: POST
    return_content: true
    headers:
      Authorization: "Bearer {{ token }}"
    body_format: json
    body: 
      contents: config-file/application.conf
      path: /destpath/on/dbfs/application.conf
```

where `config-file/application.conf` refers to a local path, i.e. where the playbook that calls `databricks_upload.yml` is located.

Here is what I tried so far :

- renaming `config-file/application.conf`, because the underscore and the dot generate base64 encoding errors as well
- changing Ansible version : Ansible-core 2.12 and 2.14
- putting the body in an actual json like this :
  `body: "{{ lookup('ansible.builtin.file','body.json') }}"`

But none of these tries had success.

I don't understand why it would expect that type of encoding there, and I am running out of ideas. What am I missing?

Comment: Please read [mre]. Your post misses debugging info. I don't think the module is expecting anything special but that your endpoint awaits for `multipart/formdata` (as in your curl example) whereas you are sending a JSON body with Ansible. But that's only a wild guess without further info.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your reply! If I understand you correctly, you find my example contains too little information to be reproducible, or too much to be minimal. Could you point out exactly what is missing or redundant please ? 
Also, about debugging info : the error message I pasted is the one I got using maximal level of verbosity (_ANSIBLE_VERBOSITY_ set to 3). If more information could be obtained by other mean, I'd be happy to update my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First and foremost, as mentioned by Zeitounator, `body_format` must be set to `form-multipart`.

But also, the way that fields must be passed in the body is — rigidly — codified. In our case, the Databricks API needs two fields : `contents` and `path`.

- `contents` is the file to be POST-ed. As a file, the reference to its path must be passed as `filename`.
- `path` is the path of the new file in dbfs. The string must be passed inside a `content` field (careful: it has nothing to do with `contents` mentioned above)

The doc alludes to this but only in the examples : it makes it hard to know whether this applies in general or only in the example.

Taking all of this into account, here is what it must look like :

```yaml
---
- name: Databricks dbfs upload
  ansible.builtin.uri:
    url: "https://<instance_name>.azuredatabricks.net/api/2.0/dbfs/put"
    method: POST
    return_content: true
    headers:
      Authorization: "Bearer {{ token }}"
    body: 
      contents: 
        filename: "config-file/application.conf"
      path: 
        content: "/destpath/on/dbfs/application.conf"
    body_format: form-multipart
```

**EDIT**

I don't fully understand this, but here's what I observed :

- Without further specification, the uploaded file will be base64-encoded, and I'll have to handle the decoding on dbfs, which is a bit annoying.
- However, as specified on the Databricks API doc, it is possible to [pass contents as base64 string](https://docs.databricks.com/api/azure/workspace/dbfs/put). So if I do the encoding myself (see snippet below), the Databricks API is able to deal with it, and will return the decoded file

Finally, syntax-wise, I found that confusing `filename` and `content` keywords could be left out by adequately using `ansible.builtin.file`. So the following two are equivalent :

```yaml
  body: 
    contents: 
      filename: "config-file/application.conf"
    path:
      content : "/destpath/on/dbfs/application.conf"
```

```yaml
  body: 
    contents: "{{ lookup('ansible.builtin.file', 'config-file/application.conf') }}"
    path : "/destpath/on/dbfs/application.conf"
```

So here's my final attempt :

```yaml
---
- name: Databricks dbfs upload
  ansible.builtin.uri:
    url: "https://<instance_name>.azuredatabricks.net/api/2.0/dbfs/put"
    method: POST
    return_content: true
    headers:
      Authorization: "Bearer {{ token }}"
    body: 
      contents: "{{ lookup('ansible.builtin.file', 'config-file/application.conf')
 |b64encode }}"
      path: "/destpath/on/dbfs/application.conf"
    body_format: form-multipart
```

Comment: I should however mention that the uploaded file will be — quite unconveniently — base64 encoded. See [here](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/73621)